# Chatify route returns json answer instead of returned normal answer after publish Chatify controller

Tags: json, laravel, routes

I am using Chatify package in Laravel. After I published controllers, after sending for example I am getting on route http://localhost:8000/moncompte/mesmessages/sendMessage, the answer {"status":"200","error":{"status":0,"message":null},"message":"<div class="flex item-start ms-3 mb-3" data-id="dd6c7d58-d583-407e-a952-dd24e2068af7">\n    <div class="media mx-2 ">\n        <img src="http://localhost:8000/file/profile_pictures/user-avatar-icon.svg" class="rounded-full max-w-15 max-h-8" alt="Dameon Prohaska Avatar">\n    </div>\n    \n    <div class="w-full">\n        <div class="mb-2">\n            <span class="font-bold">Dameon Prohaska </span>• \n            <span class="text-slate-300">04:04 AM</span> \n            \n<span class='fas fa-check' seen'></span></span>\n\n        </div>\n                <div class="message">\n            hello \n            \n                    </div>\n                \n        \n\n        \n    </div>\n</div>\n","tempID":null}.
But before the code is automatically redirect back, now it stopped and return json